# How can I open a program using PYTHON with Mutliprocessing, and send it strings from the main process?

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg, multiprocessing

I have a program that sends frames as strings to FFMPEG using something similar to:

## Working script that streams without using multiprocessing module currently on Ubuntu

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os
import subprocess as sp
import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT, KEYUP, K_ESCAPE
import pygame.display

pygame.init()
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'dummy'
pygame.display.init()
Display_Surface = pygame.display.set_mode([1280,720], 0, 32)

# FFMPEG command and settings
command = ['ffmpeg', '-framerate', '25', '-s', '1280x720', '-pix_fmt', 'rgba', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-i', '-',
           '-f', 'lavfi', '-i', 'anullsrc=cl=mono',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p','-s', 'hd720', '-r', '25', '-g', '50',
           '-f', 'flv', 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx']

pipe = sp.Popen(command, bufsize=0, stdin=sp.PIPE)

while True:
    # Quit event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pipe.stdin.write(pygame.image.tostring(Display_Surface, "RGBA"))

pipe.stdin.close()
pygame.display.quit()
os._exit()
```

This works fine, except for the fact that it is killing my CPU, which in turn causes my live stream to freeze often. The stupid GIL won't let FFMPEG run on another CPU/Core while I have 3 perfectly good cores doing nothing.

I just whipped up some code to open FFMPEG in another process. (By the way, I'm familiar with threading.Thread, but not Multiprocessing).

```
import os
import subprocess as sp
import multiprocessing

class FFMPEG_Consumer():

    def __init__(self):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.start_ffmpeg)
        proc.start()

    def start_ffmpeg(self):
        command = ['ffmpeg','-pix_fmt', 'rgba', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-i', '-',
                   '-f, 'lavfi', '-i', 'anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100',
                   '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p','-s', 'hd720', '-f', 'flv', 'rtmp://example.com']

        pipe = sp.Popen(command, bufsize=-1, stdin=sp.PIPE)

    def send_down_the_pipe(self, frame):
        pipe.stdin.write(frame)

ffmpeg = FFMPEG_Consumer()
```

For anyone that knows how to use multiprocessing, I'm sure you will immediately see that this does not work because I can't share variables this way across processes. But, it does open FFMPEG on another core.

Most online tutorials and resources focus creating pools of workers and queues to send those workers something to be processed until a job is finished. I am however trying to send a new string repeatedly to FFMPEG through each iteration.

How can I pipe my string to that process/instance of FFMPEG?

Or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

## This was the working solution (with dumbed down FFMPEG settings):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, multiprocessing
import subprocess as sp
import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT, KEYUP, K_ESCAPE
import pygame.display

pygame.init()
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'dummy'
pygame.display.init()
Display_Surface = pygame.display.set_mode([1280,720], 0, 32)

class FFMPEGConsumer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._r, self._w = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self.reader = os.fdopen(self._r.fileno(), 'r')
        self.writer = os.fdopen(self._w.fileno(), 'w', 0)
        self.proc = None

    def start_ffmpeg(self):

        command = ['ffmpeg', '-framerate', '25', '-s', '1280x720', '-pix_fmt', 'rgba', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-i', '-',
           '-f', 'lavfi', '-i', 'anullsrc=cl=mono',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p','-s', 'hd720', '-r', '25', '-g', '50',
           '-f', 'flv', 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx']
        
        self.proc = sp.Popen(command, bufsize=-1, stdin=self.reader)

    def send_down_the_pipe(self, frame):
        self.writer.write(frame)
        #print self._stdin.read()

    def __del__(self):
        self.reader.close()
        self.writer.close()

ffmpeg = FFMPEGConsumer()

while True:
    # Quit event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    ffmpeg.send_down_the_pipe(pygame.image.tostring(Display_Surface, "RGBA"))
    proc.join()

pipe.stdin.close()
pygame.display.quit()
os._exit()
```

All cores are firing and no lags so far!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can use is `multiprocessing.Pipe` for communicating with child process.

`multiprocess.Pipe` gives you two ends of pipe, where one can be used for writing and other for reading, and vice versa (if duplex flag is set to True). The thing with these two ends is that those are just file descriptors. That is why you need to open them, like files, and then read/write. To open them you must use `os.fdopen`. From then its just like reading/writing to a file.

Something like this should be of help:

```
import os
import subprocess as sp
import multiprocessing



class FFMPEG_Consumer():

    def __init__(self):
        r, w = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self._stdin = os.fdopen(r.fileno(), 'r')
        self._stdout = os.fdopen(w.fileno(), 'w')
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.start_ffmpeg)
        proc.start()

    def start_ffmpeg(self):
        command = ['ffmpeg', '-pix_fmt', 'rgba', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-i', '-', '-f',
                   'lavfi', '-i', 'anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100',
                   '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-s', 'hd720', '-f', 'flv', 'rtmp://example.com']

        sp.Popen(command, bufsize=-1, stdin=self._stdin)

    def send_down_the_pipe(self, frame):
        self._stdout.write(frame)


ffmpeg = FFMPEG_Consumer()
ffmpeg.send_down_the_pipe(frame)
```

#### Edit 1.

You can tweak buffering to better suits your needs. When you use `os.fdopen`, third argument is for buffer size. `0` is to open it without buffering at all.

#### Edit 2.

I didn't want to delete old version for educational purposes. What was the issue with my previous script?

```
class FFMPEG_Consumer():

    def __init__(self):
        r, w = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self._stdin = os.fdopen(r.fileno(), 'r')
        self._stdout = os.fdopen(w.fileno(), 'w')
        ...
```

After `__init__` method is executed, `r` and `w` file descriptors are garbage collected. Now, you have `self._stdin` and `self._stdout` that still exist and pointing to non existing file descriptors. After instantiating `FFMPEG_Consumer`, you get these errors:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
close failed in file object destructor:
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

How to solve this? You have to make sure file descriptors are preserved after `FFMPEG_Consumer` is instantiated.

Before going to example scripts that show how to solve this, let me give you couple of advices:

1. You said you use Python2.7. That is why you probably need to inherit `object` when defining class. You will see it in example script.
2. When naming class, convention is to use camel case. So `FFMPEGConsumer` is better than `FFMPEG_Consumer`.

Now onto working example.

### Working example

Here are two scripts that I used, that can give anyone a way to test how this works without using `ffmpeg`. **Attention: This is Python2.7 version.**

Script `so6_reader.py` that requires user input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(2):
        a = raw_input('Enter the string: ')
        print 'You entered %s' % a
```

Script that starts child process that starts `so6_reader.py` and writes to its standard input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import os
import multiprocessing
import subprocess as sp


class FFMPEGConsumer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._r, self._w = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self.reader = os.fdopen(self._r.fileno(), 'r')
        self.writer = os.fdopen(self._w.fileno(), 'w', 0)
        self.proc = None

    def start_ffmpeg(self):
        command = ['python', 'so6_reader.py']
        self.proc = sp.Popen(command, bufsize=0, stdin=self.reader)

    def send_down_the_pipe(self, frame):
        self.writer.write(frame)

    def __del__(self):
        self.reader.close()
        self.writer.close()


ffmpeg = FFMPEGConsumer()

proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=ffmpeg.start_ffmpeg)
proc.start()

ffmpeg.send_down_the_pipe('test 001\n')
ffmpeg.send_down_the_pipe('test 002\n')

proc.join()
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I am trying to do. I plugged it in, and now I'm getting: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainMP.py", line 441, in <module>
    ffmpeg = FFMPEG_Consumer()
  File "mainMP.py", line 408, in __init__
    self._stdin = os.fdopen(r, 'r')
TypeError: an integer is required Sorry, for the formatting in this comment, my first one. I am checking out the docs on os.fdopen now.

Comment: I did update the code. I oversaw that part since I wasn't able to run it. `Pipe` returns pair of connection objects, and `os.fdopen` requires file descriptor as first argument.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Throwing in fileno() is giving me- Traceback (most recent call last): File "mainMP.py", line 558, in <module> ffmpeg.send_down_the_pipe(frame) File "mainMP.py", line 439, in send_down_the_pipe
    self._stdout.write(frame).fileno()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
close failed in file object destructor: I am new to this, but I am reading up on them tonight. By the way, I am using Python 2.7 if that matters.

Comment: Please, check updated answer. I had to create test script that requires input so can be confident that it finally works! You just change command to the one you want and it should be working.

Comment: You have given me a lot of insight, especially as to why the threading module is preferred :). This solution is still not working for me, but I am sure it is due to my lack of knowledge. I will continue to read through the documentation until I thoroughly understand your code.

Comment: For the record, my newest error is: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainMP.py", line 446, in <module>
    ffmpeg = FFMPEGConsumer()
  File "mainMP.py", line 407, in __init__
    self.reader = os.fdopen(_r.fileno(), 'r')
NameError: global name '_r' is not defined
Exception AttributeError: "'FFMPEGConsumer' object has no attribute 'reader'" in <bound method FFMPEGConsumer.__del__ of <__main__.FFMPEGConsumer object at 0x7f96d0c5f890>> ignored

Comment: Again, I am trying to learn this as I go, but I am also trying to make consecutive writes (as strings) from a main game loop... Maybe I can't send consecutive writes to ffmpeg.send_down_the_pipe() ?

Comment: Hm, your traceback looks like you mixed parts of code. `self.reader = os.fdopen(r.fileno(), 'r')` is written if neither former nor latter code :)

Comment: I included a working stripped down script above so you can see what I'm working with. You would need a YouTube streaming key to make it work though. Oddly, I double checked the code and that is the correct error with the code above. I will double check everything again, that can't be right.

Comment: I added my most recent try which produces the error above.

Comment: you need to update `os.fdopen(_r.fileno(), 'r')` to `os.fdopen(self._r.fileno(), 'r')`. Same as for the line below.

Comment: You are awesome!!!! Now I can get back to the fun stuff. Many thanks. If I had enough points, I would totally upvote it.